# how does async affect to a function's call stack

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, asynchronous, execution

```
$('.fcb', html).each(async function() {

   const variableInfo = 'example data'  
   console.log({variableInfo });
   variableInfo = 'some other example data'
   console.log("here");

})
```

I have an asynchronous function that loops through each cheerio object and then logs the values of the variables. I want to understand async js better since I'm new to it, so bare with me. I was logging the values to console, and there was an error, which is besides the point, but as I was trying to solve the error I saw that the log looked unexpected.

```
{ variableInfo : 'example data' }
{ variableInfo : 'example data' }
{ variableInfo : 'example data' }
{ variableInfo : 'example data' }
C:\Users\user\vs code projects\project\index.js:45
            variableInfo = 'some other example data'
                       ^

TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.
```

It was weird when it logged the 'example data' for as many times as there was objects to loop. But when compared to same function without having the async keyword, it only logged the 'example data' once, and then executed the next line, which was expected.

```
{ variableInfo : 'example data' }
TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.
```

I thought that asynchronous function only affects how the code executes after the function and not inside the function block. So how come the execution cuts and jumps back before this line `variableInfo = 'some other example data'`

So clearly I don't have the greatest understanding of async js, so could somebody tell me what is really going on when you use async. All help will be appreciated thank you!

Comment: There's no `await` inside your `async` function so the function just runs normally without interruption.  It then returns a promise (all async functions return a promise), but because there are no `await` statements, that promise will already be resolved.  And, the `.each()` ignores the returned promise too.

Comment: So, in this case the function executes no differently if it is or isn't `async` as long as it doesn't throw and exception.  Ah, but I see it will throw an exception because you are trying to reassign to a const variable which throws an error.  This will lead to an uncaught promise rejection.

Comment: But, the uncaught promise rejections will probably be detected after the loop finishes because it was caught by the `async` function and turned into a rejected promise, not a normal exception.